# Metric expression of the hypertorsion of (the image of) a timelike curve in 3+1 dimensional spacetime

Tags: metric-spaces, mathematical-physics, curves, semi-riemannian-geometry

From mostly recent papers such as [these](https://search.arxiv.org/?in=&query=hypertorsion), and their common reference to papers by J. R. Letaw and J. D. Pfausch from the early 1980s, we can learn [that](https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.06329)

> *[...] a trajectory in (3 + 1)-dimensional Minkowski spacetime [...] can be characterized by three geometric invariants: the curvature $a[ ~ \tau ~ ]$, which represents the magnitude of proper acceleration, the first torsion $a[ ~ \tau ~ ]$, and the second torsion (also known as hypertorsion) $\nu[ ~ \tau ~ ]$ of the worldline. The [first and second] torsions $b[ ~ \tau ~ ]$ and $\nu[ ~ \tau ~ ]$ correspond to the proper angular velocities in a given tetrad frame*

Now, for the curvature and the torsion of (the image of) a curve in 3-dimensional Euclidean space we have (more or less well-known) corresponding **metric expressions**, i.e. in terms of (extrinsic) distances between points of a given (image of) a curve $\gamma$, at any point $P \in \gamma$:

- as **Menger curvature**: $\kappa_M[ ~ \gamma, P ~ ] := $

$$ {\large \underset{J, Q ~ \in ~ \gamma; JP ~ \lt ~ JQ, PQ ~ \lt ~ JQ \rightarrow 0 }{\underset{~}{\Large \text{Lim}}}\left[ ~ \frac{ \normalsize
 \left( (-) \begin{bmatrix} 
       0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \cr
       1 & 0 & JP^2 & JQ^2 \cr
       1 & JP^2 & 0 & PQ^2 \cr
       1 & JQ^2 & PQ^2 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} \right)^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)} 
}{\underset{JP^2 ~ PQ^2 ~ PQ^2}{~}} ~ \right] },$$

where the determinant in the denominator is of course known as a [Cayley-Menger determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula#Generalizations);

cmp. eqs. (1.2.16) and (1.2.17) of [this very new reference](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Xianfeng-Gu/publication/367117033_Classical_and_Discrete_Differential_Geometry_Theory_Applications_and_Algorithms/links/63c5bd0b6fe15d6a57250f14/Classical-and-Discrete-Differential-Geometry-Theory-Applications-and-Algorithms.pdf)

and

- the **Blumenthal metric torsion** which is expressed in terms of several Cayley-Menger determinants involving four points; cmp. eqs. (1.3.8), (1.3.15), (1.3.17).

The appeal of these metric expressions is twofold, namely:

- to be readily adaptable to the case of (timelike) (images of) curves in 3+1 dimensional flat spacetime, namely simply through replacement of the squares of distance values with values $s^2$ of (timelike) spacetime intervals;
  and moreover being readily adaptable to the case of (timelike) (images of) curves in 3+1 dimensional general spacetime, namely simply through replacement of the squares of distance values with the squares of (non-zero) Lorentzian distance values $\ell^2$; and
- being manifestly independent of any curve parametrizations, coordinate assignments, definition and selection of any frames, or somesuch.

Therefore

### My question:

How exactly is hypertorsion $\nu[ ~ \gamma, P ~ ]$ of a (suitable) (image of) a timelike curve $\gamma$ (a.k.a. timelike worldline), in 3+1 dimensional flat spacetime, in point (a.k.a. spacetime event) $P \in \gamma$ explicitly expressed in terms of values $s^2$ of (timelike) spacetime intervals of pairs of events which make up this worldline ?

Comment: This question was involuntarily migrated from https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/786939/metric-expression-of-the-hypertorsion-of-the-image-of-a-timelike-curve-in-31